# How to get the current battery statistics using a kernel module?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, hardware, c

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to get the current battery level and the charging status of the laptop using a kernel module. If possible please attach the Makefile also.

Please give a C code.

Comment: Couple things: 1) general coding questions are off-topic. Yours relates to Linux kernel, so your question may or may not be closed.  2) Your question is basically "gimme de codez". What have you tried so far ? 3) Research `/sys` filesystem. That should get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best place to start is via the /sys/class/power_supply battery uevent information. This is easy to parse to get the relevant information:

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT*/uevent

POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Unknown
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=10800000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=12408000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=0
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=93960000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=83520000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=83450000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=99
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=45N1175
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=SANYO
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=12196
```

A kernel module is not required since the kernel provides all the relevant information in a generic format for battery information via this simple user space interface.